# Can GDAL Perform Vertical Transformations?

Tags: gdal, coordinate-system, ellipsoid, geoid, vertical-transformation

Can GDAL perform vertical transformations?

If the answer is yes, please indicate which amongst these **[listed pages](http://www.gdal.org/pages.html)** can explain how exactly to accomplish vertical transformations?

If there is some other page discussing how exactly to accomplish vertical transformations, please indicate URL.

This question arises after reading Jason's question [Vertical Datum Conversion Utilities](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11672/vertical-datum-conversion-utilities/11677#11677) from a couple of years ago and the partial answer given.

Comment: Have a look at http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/wiki/VerticalDatums and search on Internet for "+geoidgrids="

Comment: That link is to an aging orphan; but it was helpful in getting to this: http://trac.osgeo.org/proj/

Comment: The page linked by @Hermann has been moved to https://github.com/OSGeo/proj.4/wiki/VerticalDatums

Comment: And this...https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/191565/vertical-datum-conversion-of-a-raster-with-gdal

Answer (score 1):

No GDAL cannot perform vertical transformations.

Comment: Are you sure? https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/191565/vertical-datum-conversion-of-a-raster-with-gdal?noredirect=1&lq=1 has a couple of recipes to do so