# Vertical transformation of DEM from NAVD88 to CGVD2013 datums

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, dem, datum

I am attempting to recalculate a DEM raster from the vertical datum of NAVD88 to the 'new' Canadian vertical datum, which is CGVD2013. I've looked at a few similar questions but they only are geoidal transformation operations in WGS84.

I've tried the following command in the OsGeo4W shell using gdal:

```
gdalwarp -s_srs "+proj=longlat +datum=NAVD88 +no_defs" -t_srs "+proj=longlat +datum=CGVD2013 +no_def" C:\OneDrive\lidar_in.tif C:\OneDrive\lidar_done.tif
```

However, gdal tells me either datum is not recognized. I've also input EPSG codes but no such luck. Any tips on this would be welcome.

**UPDATE:** Trying compound horizontal+vertical datum codes and/or names does not work either, unfortunately. Example: NAD83+NAVD88

Comment: Could you please link which Q&A you have looked at and is it possible to share some data for others to reproduce your error?

Comment: Have you downloaded the transformaion gtx files for NAVD88 and CGVD2013?  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/191565/vertical-datum-conversion-of-a-raster-with-gdal.

Comment: @Binx The link I first came across is what GBG referenced in his comment

Comment: @GBG I unfortunately haven't been able to find a gtx file for those datums - I searched through that directory in the article you linked.

Comment: You might be able to do the transformation via vDatum.  The gtx files will likely be included in the vDatum download if you want to continue with the gdal approach.   https://vdatum.noaa.gov/