# Read In SRTM HGT elevations using Java

Tags: java, srtm

I have read the following posts on reading in SRTM HGT elevations- [How do you convert SRTM HGT elevations from WGS84 into meters above sea level?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90417/how-do-you-convert-srtm-hgt-elevations-from-wgs84-into-meters-above-sea-level) and [How to extract elevation from .HGT file?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/43743/how-to-extract-elevation-from-hgt-file)  I am currently undertaking this exercise using Java on an Intel Platform. My machine "endianness" is actually little endian and so when I write this file out differently(south to north as a meteorological application requires it that way) are there any additional steps to be carried out ? My initial code checked on the endianness of the system and then read in the .hgt file appropriately. When I actually ran the weather simulation I got strange elevation values.

```
        fc = new FileInputStream(file).getChannel();
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect((int) fc.size());
        while (bb.hasRemaining()) fc.read(bb);
        bb.flip();
        sb = bb.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN).asShortBuffer();
```

Comment: Java algorithm to fix this - 1) Read in as Big Endian into a Short Buffer and 2) Write it out to the disk by querying the actual endianness. Comments ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is the Java source code for the Import SRTM tool in the open-source GIS [Whitebox GAT](http://www.uoguelph.ca/~hydrogeo/Whitebox/download.shtml), for which I am a developer. You can use it as an example for how to convert the endianness of the data to that of the system.

https://code.google.com/p/whitebox-geospatial-analysis-tools/source/browse/trunk/ImportExport/src/plugins/ImportSRTM.java

Feel free to use the code as is or to modify it as you see fit. The code is [well tested](http://whiteboxgeospatial.wordpress.com/2014/05/11/srtm-dem-data-downloader-in-whitebox-gat/) and I am confident that it works well with both SRTM-1 and SRTM-3 data. It writes the output to the Whitebox raster format (WhiteboxRaster and WhiteboxRasterBase classes), which has the endianness of whatever system is used to create the file.

Comment: Very nice WhiteboxDev ! Sometimes I feel like I must ask an SRTM question just to learn more from you !

Comment: @user311554 Ha! I'm glad to help.

Comment: It almost seems as if Whitebox GAT can do everything a GIS software can do and more!